# Рисование поверх дочерних компонентов в Swing

Tags: java, swing

Есть две панели JPanel.
Рисую их на родительской панели JPanel.
Хочу их соединить линией на родительской панели, но так, чтоб линия могла проходить по дочерним панелям.
Ниже пример в котором это не получается сделать.
Линия не видна на красном квадрате.
Просьба поделиться опытом.

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.border.Border;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
    import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

    public class TestMain {

        private static JPanel basePanel;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();

            JPanel onePanel = new JPanel(null);
            onePanel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                Border borderDefault;

                @Override
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                    borderDefault = onePanel.getBorder();
                    onePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GREEN, 5));
                    onePanel.revalidate();
                    onePanel.repaint();
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                    onePanel.setBorder(borderDefault);
                    onePanel.revalidate();
                    onePanel.repaint();
                }
            });
            onePanel.setBackground(Color.RED);
            onePanel.setOpaque(true);
            onePanel.setSize(new Dimension(20, 20));
            onePanel.setLocation(20, 20);

            JPanel twoPanel = new JPanel(null);
            twoPanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            twoPanel.setOpaque(true);
            twoPanel.setSize(new Dimension(20, 20));
            twoPanel.setLocation(50, 50);

            basePanel = new JPanel(null) {
                @Override
                protected void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {
                    super.paintComponent(graphics);
                    Point one = onePanel.getLocationOnScreen();
                    Point two = twoPanel.getLocationOnScreen();
                    if (basePanel != null) {
                        SwingUtilities.convertPointFromScreen(one, basePanel);
                        SwingUtilities.convertPointFromScreen(two, basePanel);
                        graphics.drawLine(one.x - 10, one.y - 10, two.x, two.y);
                    }
                }
            };
            basePanel.setSize(100, 100);
            basePanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
            basePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
            basePanel.add(onePanel);
            basePanel.add(twoPanel);

            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(basePanel);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать GlassPane:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class TestMain {

    private static JPanel basePanel;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        JPanel onePanel = new JPanel(null);
        onePanel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            Border borderDefault;

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                borderDefault = onePanel.getBorder();
                onePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GREEN, 5));
                onePanel.revalidate();
                onePanel.repaint();
                basePanel.repaint();
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                onePanel.setBorder(borderDefault);
                onePanel.revalidate();
                onePanel.repaint();
                basePanel.repaint();
            }
        });
        onePanel.setBackground(Color.RED);
        onePanel.setOpaque(true);
        onePanel.setSize(new Dimension(20, 20));
        onePanel.setLocation(20, 20);

        JPanel twoPanel = new JPanel(null);
        twoPanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        twoPanel.setOpaque(true);
        twoPanel.setSize(new Dimension(20, 20));
        twoPanel.setLocation(50, 50);

        basePanel = new JPanel(null);
        basePanel.setSize(100, 100);
        basePanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        basePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        basePanel.add(onePanel);
        basePanel.add(twoPanel);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(basePanel);



        frame.setGlassPane(new JPanel() {
            {
                setOpaque(false);
            }
            
            @Override
            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                Point one = onePanel.getLocationOnScreen();
                Point two = twoPanel.getLocationOnScreen();
                if (basePanel != null) {
                    SwingUtilities.convertPointFromScreen(one, basePanel);
                    SwingUtilities.convertPointFromScreen(two, basePanel);
                    g.drawLine(one.x - 10, one.y - 10, two.x, two.y);
                }
            }
        });
        frame.getGlassPane().setVisible(true);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Вот так это тоже будет работать, но вообще крайне не рекомендуется переопределять метод `paint`.

```js
    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.border.Border;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
    import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
    
    public class TestMain {
    
        private static JPanel basePanel;
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    
            JPanel onePanel = new JPanel(null);
            onePanel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                Border borderDefault;
    
                @Override
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                    borderDefault = onePanel.getBorder();
                    onePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GREEN, 5));
                    onePanel.revalidate();
                    onePanel.repaint();
                    basePanel.repaint();
                }
    
                @Override
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                    onePanel.setBorder(borderDefault);
                    onePanel.revalidate();
                    onePanel.repaint();
                    basePanel.repaint();
                }
            });
            onePanel.setBackground(Color.RED);
            onePanel.setOpaque(true);
            onePanel.setSize(new Dimension(20, 20));
            onePanel.setLocation(20, 20);
    
            JPanel twoPanel = new JPanel(null);
            twoPanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            twoPanel.setOpaque(true);
            twoPanel.setSize(new Dimension(20, 20));
            twoPanel.setLocation(50, 50);
    
            basePanel = new JPanel(null) {
                @Override
                public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
                    super.paint(graphics);
                    Point one = onePanel.getLocationOnScreen();
                    Point two = twoPanel.getLocationOnScreen();
                    if (basePanel != null) {
                        SwingUtilities.convertPointFromScreen(one, basePanel);
                        SwingUtilities.convertPointFromScreen(two, basePanel);
                        graphics.drawLine(one.x - 10, one.y - 10, two.x, two.y);
                    }
                }
            };
            basePanel.setSize(100, 100);
            basePanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
            basePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
            basePanel.add(onePanel);
            basePanel.add(twoPanel);
    
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(basePanel);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Из-за того, что не рекомендуется, и задан вопрос. Мне нужно отрисовывать около 2 500 линий. не хотелось бы постоянно нагружать paint. Здесь только кэшировать наверно подойдет... В общим других вариантов нет?

Comment: но это как раз тот случай, Вам нужно влезть в область отрисовки детей, это как раз то, из-за чего не рекомендуется `paint` переопределять, Вы ломаете логику отрисовки дочерних компонентов

Comment: есть еще glasspane, можно на нем нарисовать, сейчас дополню ответ

Comment: Спасибо Вам, уважаемый, про GlassPane тоже знаю, но она мне не подходит в силу того, что относится ко всему окну. Буду думать как оптимизировать отрисовку в paint.

Comment: @ezhov_da да нет проблем, Вы какую-то блок-схему рисуете?

Comment: Вы абсолютно правы, реализую приложение по отрисовке зависимостей.

Comment: @ezhov_da  рисуйте все на одной панельке, так будет проще, без вложенных компонентов

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95907/discussion-between-ezhov-da-and-stranger-in-the-q).